# Displaying difference of two datetime database fields in Hours:Minutes (i.e. 8:34h)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have two datetime fields in database -> clock_in and clock_out

On my view i have:

```
<td><%= ((r.clock_out - r.clock_in) / 1.hour).to_i %> </td>
```

This displays -> only hours, i.e. 2 or 0 or 3 etc. Doesn't display minutes.

How do I display minutes as well? i.e. 2:45h

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out, I used this:**

```
<%= Time.at(((r.clock_out - r.clock_in) / 1.second).to_i).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
```